# How to compare the string character by character to a character?

Tags: c++

when i run this on gdb it does not goes into if statement even when the condition are met

for example
input: 000
The first if should be true but is false

Here is full code
The program is supposed to check if all the 1s occurring in the string are in continuous manner

Thanks..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int trials = 0;
 cin>>trials;
 cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
 while(trials--)
 {
   string line;
   getline(cin,line);

   int i = 0;
   int n = line.length();

   int d = 0;
   int u = 0;
   int flag = 0;


   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
   if(line[i] == '0')
     {
       flag = 1;
     }
   if(line[i] == '0' && line[i + 1] == '1' && d == 0)
     {
      u++;

     }
   else if(line[i] == '1' && line[i + 1] == '0' && u == 1)
     {
       d++;
     }
 }
   if(flag == 0)
cout<<"YES"<<endl;
   else if(u ==1 && d == 1)
 {
   cout<<"YES"<<endl;
 }
   else
 cout<<"NO"<<endl;


 }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `line` right after `getline`? Have you inspected it using GDB?

Comment: the contents of the line are same "000"

Comment: Let's begin by you telling us what this is supposed to do. Btw, just executed it, the first if IS evaluated true, on http://cpp.sh/8vwn - therefore: did you even used a debugger at this point in time?

Comment: @nickyc   Also when i print this if statement in gdb it gives true

Comment: You have 3 if statements there. and how do you print an if statement?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your 0s and 1s are binary, then if you can convert your string to some nice machine representation, then you can do this sort of test in a one-liner. Get your hands on a copy of Hacker's Delight and go to page 12 (in the 2nd edition):

```
((x & -x) + x) & x
```

(turns off all contiguous rightmost 1s, so if the result is 0 then your condition is met)